# How long would atmospheric oxygen last on Earth if plants stopped making it?

Tags: kinetics, atmospheric-chemistry

A few years ago a rather dubious paper appeared in a mathematical biology journal. The gist of it was that warming oceans could stop oceanic plankton making oxygen (according to a somewhat simplistic model). If this happened, one of the authors claimed that sea-level air could be reduced to the oxygen levels at the top of everest in 100 years. [This report](https://russgeorge.net/2016/06/17/plankton-will-stop-making-oxygen-by-end-of-century/) quotes one author saying:

> By 2100, the earth at sea level could have atmospheric oxygen levels comparable to the top of Mount Everest today. And as far as I know, people cannot normally stay on Everest without oxygen masks for more than a few minutes...

This poses several problems and the authors have subsequently modified their claims.

So I posed a question about it on [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/38300/3943) but that got bogged down in arguments about whether answers counted as original research.

So I thought I'd ask a simpler, but relevant, question here since the result is about atmospheric chemistry. Let's assume all oxygen production on earth has stopped. How long would the oxygen in the atmosphere last?

NB I'm not interested in the model (it has been widely rubbished). I'm interested in the basic facts of atmospheric chemistry which should be a far simpler background question to answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because it's rather about [EarthScience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) then chemistry.

Comment: Also what's the criterion of "lasting" would be - partial pressure on Everest?

Comment: @mithoron WE have an atmospheric chemistry tag. It is as good a question here as it would be on earth science especially since we don't need any special knowledge about atmospheric processes to answer it. A simple answer would need an estimate of the total amount of oxygen and how rapidly it is used. basic calculations do the rest. But feel free to move if you disagree.

Comment: @Mithoron A simple calculation of the result would state its premises in the calculation and define the end point. enough of a loss to get to Everest-levels is a good as any other end point.

Comment: Maybe getting too much in the weeds, but for humans the ratio of oxygen to carbon dioxide may be the most important value so one should also account for decreased CO2 uptake by photosynthesizing organisms?

Comment: It's not a matter of atmospheric chemistry - lowering of O2 would be caused by respiration, decay of plant leftovers, fire and uncountable other effects - most of them close to the surface of Earth, more of an atmospheric effects, like oxidation of emitted  gases would be secondary.

Comment: Well, it's not like I can migrate it, but this question seems poorly defined. It's more of something for xkcd What If? then SE. Highly speculative scenarios need to be very precisely defined to make a specific answer possible.

Comment: @mithoron I'm not sure why it is poorly defined. Three simple observations: the atmosphere is in equilibrium; We have estimates as to how much photosynthesis occurs each year; the stock of oxygen is known. So what happens if we make no more oxygen? That's a clear scenario that should put the estimate in the controversial quote in context. More complex analysis is not required.